# Copy VBA Auto increment cell in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with multiple columns, One column has reference(s) to previous (just like in MS-Project),

I am trying to get the row numbers for each of the reference(s) using the below function, this works well.

```
Public Function Splitter() As String
Dim multiRef() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, rowNumber As Integer
Dim multiValue As String

Dim rowIndex As String, tempValue As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    rowNumber = ActiveCell.row
    multiValue = ws.Range("T" & rowNumber).Value
    multiRef = Split(multiValue, ";")

    For i = 0 To UBound(multiRef)
        If ((StrComp(Trim(multiRef(i)), "-") = 0) Or (StrComp(Trim(multiRef(i)), "Applicable") = 0) Or (StrComp(Trim(multiRef(i)), "") = 0) Or (StrComp(Trim(multiRef(i)), "TBD") = 0) Or (StrComp(Trim(multiRef(i)), "Y") = 0)) Then
        Else:
             tempValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(multiRef(i)), ws.Range("E2:E1500"), 0)
             If (Not IsNull(tempValue)) Then
                 rowIndex = rowIndex & tempValue & ", "
             End If
        End If

    Next i

If (Len(rowIndex) <= 0) Then
    Splitter_System = ""
    Else: Splitter_System = Left(rowIndex, Len(rowIndex) - 2)
End If
```

End Function

The problem is that when I copy the same to the below cells, it just copies the same content, and unless I manually edit each row the data is not updated.

Is there an easier way to update the value automatically?

Comment: Are you calling this function from a formula in cell? If this is the case then I would suggest you don't use the reference ActiveCell because this doesn't reference the cell that particular function iteration is running for but rather the global reference of what cell you have currently highlighted/selected. A better way is to build a function that takes as input the range of where your raw information is, and outputs the extracted information. Please let me know if I am not on the right path

Comment: @nbayly, you are on the right track. Can you suggest the best way forward by an example?

Comment: Please review my proposed answer below. Let me know if you need any further assistance. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveCell reference should not be used inside a Function. You can rather reference the input range but requiring it as a function input variable and then having your function return the processed output. For example:

```
Public Function Splitter(CellReference As Range) As String
    Dim multiRef() As String
    multiValue = CellReference.Value2
    .
    .
    .
    Splitter = tempValue

End Function
```

You can then in your cell call your formula as:

```
U5 =SPLITTER(T5)
```

And when you copy down it will vary the input cell reference relative to the target cell, ie `U6 = SPLITTER(T6)`

As I noticed you have also a hardcoded range that you do a `Match` on, you can also have that range as an input if it also varies through your dataset.

Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: @nbayla, Brilliant, its almost been 5 years since I last worked on VBS